# AttributeError: 'user_list' object has no attribute '_ignore_model_permissions'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm going through the django REST framework tutorial, except replacing the Snippet model with my own custom User model. However, when I try to test out the API, I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 326, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 314, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 235, in initial
    self.check_permissions(request)
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 192, in check_permissions
    if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
  File "/Users/AndyFang/Desktop/doorstep-django/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/permissions.py", line 131, in has_permission
    if model_cls is None and getattr(view, '_ignore_model_permissions'):
AttributeError: 'user_list' object has no attribute '_ignore_model_permissions'
```

I've tried various things to fix this (such as disabling the format feature, adding csrf_exmept token, etc.) all to no avail. Below is the code I wrote:

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'phone_number', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list(request, format=None):
  """
  List all users, or create a new user.
  """
  if request.method == 'GET':
    users = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def user_detail(request, pk, format=None):
  """
  Retrieve, update or delete a user instance.
  """              
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
  except User.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

  if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = UserSerializer(user)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  elif request.method == 'PUT':
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
      return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

  elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    user.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**urls.py**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a bit of a bug there, AttributeError shouldn't be raised there - I've just fixed that in master now.

Instead what you'll see when you run against master now is this assertion error:

```
Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissions on a view that does not have `.model` or `.queryset` property.
```

The issue here is that the `DjangoModelPermissions` class can only work if it has a way of determining which model permissions are required for the view.  If you want to use that permission class, you'll need to re-write your views as class based views, and ensure they have the `model` attribute set appropriately.

Note that just because you re-write them as class-based views that doesn't mean you need to use the generic class based views, you can still keep the explicit view logic you currently have.  Something like this:

```
class UserListView(views.APIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = self.queryset
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):     
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
          serializer.save()
          return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
          return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserDetailView(views.APIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, pk)
        try:
            return self.queryset.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Note the use of `queryset` in both cases means the `DjangoModelPermissions` will now be able to be applied to these views.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have the `DjangoModelPermissions` or similar set as a default permission class in your settings. Something like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
    )
}
```

This will by default check if a user has permissions on the model your view is based on. If you view doesn't have a model set on it, it can't find out the permissions. So you need to set the model on the view. This is as far as I can see only possible in a class based APIView:

```
from .models import MyModel

class MyView(APIView):

    model = MyModel

    def get(self, request, pk):
        # ...
```

In case your view is not based on a Django model, you can either remove this default class from your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings, or set a custom permission class on your view, like:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class MyView(APIView)

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        # ...
```

Or in a function based view as:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
def my_view(request)
    # ...
```

For more info about permissions see http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest:

```
 @api_view(['POST'])
 @permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
 def my_view(request)
 # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the rest framework tutorial at the moment as well, rather than rewrite me views as I'm pretty novice  I just changed the permissions settings in my settings.py for the framework to the below and all seems good as I'm no longer taking permissions from the model.

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
```

Comment: Just discovered an issue with this - works great in browser as I'm authenticated, however using curl, I'm not  so complains that there are no authentication details :(